# Why i got diffrent variables types using pagination? (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-9

I have weird problem, i got 2 different types of returning data from pagination:

- first page items->items is numeric array

[image: numeric array]

- rest of pages items->items is associative array

[image: associative array]

Why is this happening, here is code

```
$models = Model::withTranslation()->with(['relation' => function ($relation) {
            $relation->withTranslation();
        }
        }])->get();

        return $models->paginate(self::PER_PAGE);
```

relation is one to one, translation package is https://docs.astrotomic.info/laravel-translatable, self::PER_PAGE = 10

Comment: sorry, i was in hurry, the first one is numeric array, the second one is associative array, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I will correct it right away

Answer (score 1):

I just find out the reason, but I still posted the problem, maybe someone would save some time. I just changed this:

```
->get()->paginate(10)
to this:
->paginate(10)
```

Comment: Well yes, you don't use `get()` (or `all()`) when using [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination)

Comment: I am aware of that, but it's not throwing any exception, so i wanted to reduce time of resolving this problem for people which just like me haven't noticed the typo